# Is there a faster way to randomize a set of ordered numbers?

Tags: arrays, random, big-o

I made this game that's currently on the App Store called "Twinstones", and there is a "stone" selection Store page that allows you to choose what set of stones you'd like to play with (60 choices).

I wrote a randomizing function to make the stone options located in different column-row spots for different users.  In terms of Big-O constraints, is my function considered linear on a logarithmic scale?  Or is there, given an input of 10000 instead of 60, something that increases the time beyond reasonable means?  I'm very new to this world of time-managed code, so bear with me:

```
#define STONES 60

- (void)randomizeStones {
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    char stone[STONES];
    char tester[STONES] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
                       21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,
                       39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,
                       57,58,59};


    int tracker = STONES;
    for (int i = 0; i < STONES; i++) {
        int r = rand() % tracker;
        stone[i] = tester[r];
        tester[r] = ' ';
        for (int j = r; j < tracker; j++) {
           tester[j] = tester[j+1];
           tester[j+1] = ' ';
        }
        tracker--;
    }
    // print out Stones order to verify (this function works just to throw that in there)
}
```

1. Given the 60 number set, I get a random number of the current amount.
2. That number gets "transferred" from the `tester` array to the first element of the `stone` array.
3. Then, I remove that number from the index position in `tester`.
4. The second `for` loop takes the values in the indexes greater than the chosen index and "moves" them one to the left in the `tester` array order.
5. Then `tracker` is reduced by one to prevent the second `for` loop from constantly running 60 times around.

How efficient is this process (given that I want n Stones to be uniquely randomized without having to randomize on and on to find unique values)?

Comment: What language are you looking for?  I just want to confirm, as you mentioned appstore i'm guessing Java?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: Sorry, App Store as in iOS....Coded it in Objective-C, this is example is in C.

Comment: John that's great, didn't know that existed...it completely eliminates my second array! My solution was O(n^2) order